# Why are my deep learning models giving unreasonably high accuracy on test data?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, natural-language, keras, text-mining

I'm trying to do sarcasm detection on Twitter data to replicate the results mentioned in this [paper](https://aclanthology.org/2020.wnut-1.2.pdf). Binary classification problem. For that I used a separate set of **unlabeled** tweets to create the embedding matrix using Word2Vec model. Before doing that I preprocessed the **unlabeled** data and removed the rare words as mentioned in the paper. Code is as follows:

```
model = Word2Vec(df_hing_eng['tweet_text'], vector_size=300, window=10, hs=0, negative = 1)
embedding_size = model.wv.vectors.shape[1]
```

Next I fit a tokenizer on this **unlabeled** data:

```
tok = Tokenizer()
tok.fit_on_texts(df_hing_eng['tweet_text'])
vocab_size = len(tok.word_index) + 1
```

Next, I created the embedding matrix as follows:

```
word_vec_dict={}
for word in vocab:
    word_vec_dict[word]=model.wv.get_vector(word)

embed_matrix=np.zeros(shape=(vocab_size,embedding_size))
for word,i in tok.word_index.items():
    embed_vector=word_vec_dict.get(word)
    if embed_vector is not None:  
        embed_matrix[i]=embed_vector
```

Now, I'm using a separate set of **labeled** tweets to be used as training and test data (for the DL models). I used the same preprocessing steps as the `unlabeled` data and removed the same rare words we found in the `unlabeled` data. Now I find the maximum length of all tweets in the **labeled** data.

```
maxi = -1
for row in df_labeled.loc[:,'tweet_text']:
    if len(row)>maxi:
        maxi = len(row)
```

After that I used the tokenizer, that I fit on the **unlabeled** data, to create the word indices for the **labeled** data as follows:

```
encoded_tweets = tok.texts_to_sequences(df_labeled['tweet_text'])
```

Now I padded the **labeled** data to the length of the maximum tweets among the **labeled** data.

```
padded_tweets = pad_sequences(encoded_tweets, maxlen=maxi, padding='post')
```

Finally, I split the **labeled** data into training and test data as follows,

```
x_train,x_test,y_train,y_test=train_test_split(padded_tweets, df_labeled['is_sarcastic'], test_size=0.10, random_state=42)
```

**Is there any data leakage anywhere from training to test data or any other problem?** Almost all of my DL models are giving more than 90% accuracy contrary to the original paper which reported a maximum of 75% accuracy. The codes for DL models were written by the authors of the papers. I used the same parameters as they mentioned.

The tokenizer was actually fit on a completely different **unlabeled** data that is absolutely separate from (**labeled**) training and test data.